# Mosquitto log files not generating

Tags: logging, mqtt, mosquitto

In **mosquitto** broker, there are some configurations to write event log files. I am using following configurations and running the broker.

```
log_type all
log_dest file /root/Files/mosquitto.log
log_facility 5
```

Although, I don't see any logs being generated in the location `/root/Files/mosquitto.log`

What could be the problem? I'm using centos 6.7

Edit... 
**Following are the config file contents**

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/plugin.so

listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

message_size_limit 268435455

log_type all 
log_dest file /root/Files/mosquitto.log
log_facility 5
```

Comment: How are you starting mosquitto?

Comment: **mosquitto -v -c customConfig.conf** 

Is that what you asked?

Comment: @hardillb added the whole config file content to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the '-v' on the command line.

Running mosquitto --help give the following

> ...
>
> -v : verbose mode - enable all logging types. This overrides
>         any logging options given in the config file.
>
> ...

The important bit being the second sentence which is disabling all the logging directives in the config file

Try without the '-v'

Comment: I tried without the verbose mode, but still no log file is being generated.  Terminal doesn't show any logs either.

Comment: What version of mosquitto and CentOS?

Comment: Sorry, spotted the centos version in the question. Also what user are you running mosquitto as and do they have write access to /root/Files?

Comment: I was already running root user. Although there were some access problems. chmod did the trick. Thanks.